# Persistent ModuleNotFoundError: No module named after setting path to project on Windows OS

Tags: python-3.x, windows, code-coverage, python-unittest

In my attempts to run coverage in the terminal `coverage run mytestsuite.py -v` on this code:

```
import unittest
import coverage
import mytestsuite as testSuite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cov = coverage.Coverage()
    cov.start()
    framework = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(testSuite)

    test_result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(framework).wasSuccessful()
    cov.stop()
    cov.save()

    print("\nTesting Concluded with result:", test_result)
    cov.html_report()
```

I am observing the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysource.py'

where mysource.py is imported into mytestsuite.py using the following syntax:
`import sourcefolder.mysource as src`

If I run mytestsuite.py in the IDE, I see the following output:

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Anthem
> Rukiya\IdeaProjects\DiTTo_YoutubePredictor\test\youtubePredictor_testRunner.py",
> line 33, in 
> cov.html_report()   File "C:\Users\Anthem Rukiya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py",
> line 972, in html_report
> return reporter.report(morfs)   File "C:\Users\Anthem Rukiya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\coverage\html.py",
> line 241, in report
> for fr, analysis in get_analysis_to_report(self.coverage, morfs):   File "C:\Users\Anthem
> Rukiya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\coverage\report.py",
> line 66, in get_analysis_to_report
> raise CoverageException("No data to report.") coverage.misc.CoverageException: No data to report.
>
> Testing Concluded with result: True
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I am currently running Python 3.9.2 on Windows OS in IntelliJ and have attempted setting my project file as the python path using the following command in the command prompt:
set PYTHONPATH%PYTHONPATH%;C:\path_to_my_project_folder

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apologies, this should actually read:
"If I run mytestrunner.py in the IDE, I see the following output:" mytestrunner.py is the file in which the above code snippet is featured.

Comment: You don't need to use both the "coverage run" command and the "import coverage" technique.  Just use "coverage run".

Comment: @NedBatchelder thank you for your assistance.  I also found some insight here https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash/issues/94 which helped resolve the build failure on Travis.  By the way, love your github page and Coverage.  Thank you for such an awesome contribution to the automated testing and continuous integration world at large.  My classmates and I have been utilizing your work for school for the last two years in every class for class projects.